# Does value change when we clone an object, change certain values and add it to an arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

**Snippet:**

```java
List<Item> cartList= new ArrayList<Item>();

for(Item correctDataOfItem: correctDataList){

Item clonedItem=response.getItem().clone();

clonedItem = populateCartItem(correctDataOfItem, clonedItem);

/*In populateCartItem(), we set different values of item in clonedItem with the values from correctDataOfItem and return the clonedItem (with new values set)
*/

cartList.add(clonedItem);

}
```

**Question:**

While adding an element to the ArrayList, the data is correct. After each new element is added to the list, some data of the previous element is getting changed. Why is it so?

Comment: My guess is that you are doing a shallow clone, and some of the underlying state is the same, and is being overwritten with each addition.

Comment: another possibility would be static fields in the `Item` class. It would be better if you could show us some code from the `Item` class and the `populateCartItem()` method

Comment: can you share `clone` method's implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. There are no static fields in Item class and populateCartItem() method

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and @ gati sahu Thanks, it worked after deep cloning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default version of clone() method creates the shallow copy of an object. The shallow copy of an object will have exact copy of all the fields of original object. If original object has any references to other objects as fields, then only references of those objects are copied into clone object, copy of those objects are not created. That means any changes made to those objects through clone object will be reflected in original object or vice-versa.Can you please check your clone process